# php - ./yiic rresque start does nothing

Tags: php, yii, resque, yiic, php-resque

I installed this extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-resque/

```
user@host:/path/to/protected$ ./yiic rresque start
Yii command runner (based on Yii v1.1.13)
Usage: ./yiic <command-name> [parameters...]

The following commands are available:
 - message
 - migrate
 - shell
 - webapp

To see individual command help, use the following:
   ./yiic help <command-name>
```

What's might be wrong?

**EDIT**

I figured out the problem: I didn't put RResqueCommand.php into ./protected/commands folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **RResqueCommand.php** inside protected/commands

According the [yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console):

> Console commands are stored as class files under the directory specified by `CConsoleApplication::commandPath`.

By default, this refers to the directory `protected/commands`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your config/console.php:

```
'import' => array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```